# how do I change this sql query [Select MAX(id)] to linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I do this in LINQ?

```
SELECT MAX(ptc.idProducto_Talle_Color), t.idTalle, t.Numero 
FROM Producto_Talle_Color ptc INNER JOIN Talle t ON ptc.Talle_idTalle = t.idTalle
WHERE ptc.Producto_idProducto = 3
GROUP BY t.idTalle, t.Numero
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: here is something that you can look at and apply to your already existing code I would suggest putting in a little more effort in regards to a google search as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386922(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `linq` your answer is:

```
var res = from y in (
from ptc in context.Producto_Talle_Color
 where ptc.Producto_idProducto == 3  
group ptc by ptc.Talle_idTalle 
into grouedres select 
new {max=grouedres.Max(x=>x.idProducto_Talle_Color),id=g.Key}
)
 join t in context.Talle on y.id equals t.idTalle 
select {max,t.idTalle, t.Numero};
```

Answer (score 1):

with `lambda expression` your answer is:

```
var res=context.Talle.Select(t=>
t.idTalle, 
t.Numero,
t.Producto_Talle_Color.Max(ptc=>ptc.idProducto_Talle_Color)
).Where(t=>t.Producto_Talle_Color.Producto_idProducto == 3);
```